# Any Open Source Android utility that allows me to easily identify a color in a picture?

Tags: android, open-source, camera, color

I need the ability to open a picture up in Android and have *something* identify a color from that picture, giving me the hex value of the pixel. This is pretty simple. I need this so I can take pictures of buildings and tag them in OpenStreetMaps. Is there a utility that will allow me to easily do this?

Comment: Given that you are familiar with [F-Droid site](https://f-droid.org/), you might want to point out what you've tried and how it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: …and as it's been migrated from the android site, you now need to mention what platform is required. Some platforms, eg Mac, have this ability inbuilt. Others don't.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a [color picker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nauj27.android.colorpicker&hl=en_AU&gl=US), I googled for one that supposedly is free and "no ads" and found that one, there are others that are way more popular and downloads in the millions, but they have ads...